# Validated element list like a*b?a*

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to validate with XSD a XML that looks like this :

```
<list>
 <item />
 <selecteditem />
 <item />
 <item />
</list>
```

the LIST can contains several ITEM but only one SELECTEDITEM that can be placed wherever within the LIST element.

However, I did not find any expression in XSD that can allow me to validate that and when I try some "naive" attemps like

```
<xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="item" type="option" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="selecteditem" type="option" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="item" type="option" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I get a message indicating that my model is not determinist which makes me doubt that what i am trying is actually impossible.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to validate this or if XSD isn't meant to do that (and what am i doing wrong).

Thanks.

EDIT: here is another solution i tried :

```
<xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="itemselected" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I am afraid that the message is correct. There is no way to validate this. You could go with an optional boolean attribute in the item element, `selected`, to have the result you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be expressed as

```
item* (selectedItem item*)?
```

Comment: Indeed, expression is equivalent. however, converted in XSD by xs:sequence of ITEM and ITEMSELECT within the xs:sequence of ITEM, i still get the error message that the model isn't determinist. Looks like XSD cannot validate this type of constraint.

Comment: I think it's valid and unambiguous, can you show the XSD translation that you tried?

Comment: Your edited version works for me. How are you processing it, and what error do you get?

Comment: I am using php 5.3 and lib DOM (DOM/XML API Version : 20031129 - libxml Version 2.6.26). I validate my xml using the function DOMDocument::schemaValidate() and obtain the error "local complex type: The content model is not determinist." (no more detail, but related to this part of the xsd since it works when I change/remove it)

Comment: I'm afraid that sounds to me like a bug in libxml. The schema is definitely valid. It looks very like the bug being discussed here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=924785 which appears to have a solution.